# Saving vectorized circuits in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

Is there a way to save vectorized images in Qiskit? I am using

```
circuit.draw('latex', filename='./file.pdf')
```

They type of the image is a pdf, but it looks like a png exported as a pdf. For reference I attach here a figure of the differences I point out.

[image]

Hopefully some differences can be noticed. The top subfigure was made with `Quantikz`, while the other directly with `Qiskit`. The difference that the top is vectorized and the other looks like it isn't.

**EDIT:**

The problem is solved using what luciano pointed out. I just want to add that the resulting pdf circuit may still need some cleaning. Apparently the figure is not "tight framed", I attach an example of what I mean

[image]

The letters that appear at the bottom are part of the figure caption. One can see that there's a huge space between the image and the caption, along with a border that frames the image.

Comment: For Googlers, `.svg` output seems to work fine nowadays, useful for certain use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `'latex_source'` you can save the LaTeX file and compile it later with pdflatex

In an interactive console (such a Jupyter notebook), you can run the following:

```
circuit.draw('latex_source', filename='./file.tex')
!pdflatex file.tex
```

This will create a file.pdf in actual PDF format.

(I understand this is very unintuitive, [I submitted a fix to it](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/6446))

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. The docs are a little bit confusing in this part. I will add some extra feature that I find, hopefully this can also be corrected in the upcoming patches.

Comment: if you need to insert the circuit image in another latex file, you can paste the relevant part of `latex_source` output in it.

Comment: Ok, I just thought that something similar to `bbox_inches='tight'` could be made here (it could help when writting thesis or papers).